# DataFrame is saving brackets while exporting to csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like this.

[DataFrame picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPNm2.png)

I thought of save a tuple of two values under a column and then retrieve whichever value is needed. But now, for example, if I want the first value in the tuple located at the first row of the 'Ref' column, I get "(" instead of "c0_4"

```
df = pd.read_csv(df_path)
print(df['Ref'][0][0])
```

The output for this is "(" and not "c0_4".

I don't want to use split() because I want the values to be searchable in the dataframe. For example, I would want to search for "c0_8" under the "Ref" column and get the row.

What other alternatives do I have to save two values in a row under the same column?

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that you're simply accessing character 0 of a string.

`file` is character-oriented storage; there is no "data frame" abstraction.  Hence, we use CSV to hold the columnar data as text, a format that allows easy output and input recovery.

A CSV file consists only of text, with the separator character and newline having special meanings.  There is no "tuple" form.  Your data frame is stored as string data.  If you want to recover your original tuple form, you will need to write parsing code to convert the strings back to tuples.  Alternately, you can switch to a  "pickle" (PCL) format for storing your data.

That should be enough leads to allow you to research whatever alternatives you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is stored as a string

To format it into a tuple, split every string in your DataFrame and save it back as a tuple, with something like:

for n...

for m...

df[n][m] = (df[n][m].split(",")[0][1:], df[n][m].split(",")[1][:-1])